# java interface generics casting problem

Tags: java, generics

The method add(capture#2-of ? extends IObject) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (IDerived)

```
protected List<? extends IObject> getObjects()
{
    List<? extends IObject> objects = new ArrayList<IObject>();
    for (String id: item_ids)
    {
        IDerived object = (IDerived) readObject(id);
        objects.add(object); #error
    }
    return objects;
}

interface IDerived extends interface IVersionedObject extends interface IObject
```

If I change the type of objects to List then the error goes away, which makes no sense because it has to make exactly the same cast to the function return type.

Comment: Shouldn't your `objects` be instantiated as `new ArrayList<IDerived>()`?

Comment: @biziclop, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: I might have went overboard with my answer. I thought you where asking why vs how-to-fix-it.

Comment: @finnw Because I didn't have Eclipse at hand to test that it compiles and I had no time to write up an explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected <T extends IObject> List<T> getObjects() {
    List<T> objects = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (String id: item_ids)
    {
        T object = (T) readObject(id);
        objects.add(object); // NO error
    }
    return objects;
}
```

EDIT (short explanation):

This way your method will work fine with any subtype of IObject (the lists and casts inside get to be generic) and the return type will be inferred from the caller's expectations (as you apparently intended).

In response to the comment, you can now call the getObjects() method in the following ways:

```
// This should only be used if readObject() behaves like
// getObjects() and is able to return any requested subtype.
// Otherwise, you'll get a ClassCastException when trying to get
// something from the derivedList in case readObject() put something
// else there (which is not a subtype of IDerived).
List<IDerived> derivedList = getObjects();

// This is the safe way to go in case you don't have
// full control over what readObject() returns.
// But if you're using it like this (all the time), you'd better
// return List<IObject> from getObjects() and get rid
// of generics.
List<? extends IObject> objectList1 = getObjects();
List<IObject> objectList2 = getObjects();
```

Comment: +1...and the caller can always cast/store the result as a `List<? extends IObject>` anyway if that's really what they want.

Comment: Oh wait I didn't see the unchecked cast in the middle there.  That's a bit yuck.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I am going to explain this right but here I go.

```
List<? extends IObject> objects = new ArrayList<IObject>();
```

Says that the list is of an unknown type that extends IObject. Even though you put a `new ArrayList<IObject>();` on the rhs, the list generic type is still not tightly defined. In other words, the generic type does not get "baked" in when you assign a reference to it.

So, when you call `objects.add(object);` The type checker doesn't know that the list will be compatible with IDerived because the list could be of type `IVersionedObjectSomethingElse`. Even though that's impossible from you flow of logic it's possible to constuct.

```
List<? extends IObject> objects = null;
if (test) { 
    objects = new ArrayList<IObject>();
}
else {
    objects = new ArrayList<IVersionedObject2>();
}

objects.add( (IDerived) iDerivedObj ); // iDerived *might* not be compatible
```

Answer (score -1):

Why the wildcards? Instead of `? extends IObject`, use `IDerived`

Change this line

```
List<? extends IObject> objects = new ArrayList<IObject>();
```

to this:

```
List<IDerived> objects = new ArrayList<IDerived>();
```

And change

```
protected List<? extends IObject> getObjects()
```

to

```
protected List<IDerived> getObjects()
```