# Java generics help

Tags: java, generics

I have `class A` and a `class B` that extends `A`.

I have an abstract `class X` and a concrete class `Y` that extends `X`.

In `X` I have an abstract method with the following signature:

```
public abstract Collection<? extends A> getStuff();
```

In `Y` I implement the abstract method with the following signature:

```
public Collection<B> getStuff();
```

When I try to do the following: `classX.getStuff().add(B)`

It gave the following complaint: **add (capture ) in Collection cannot be applied to B**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the complaint?

Comment: Why are you talking about the signature for `getStuff()` if your problem is with the method `add()`? Or is `classX` the collection returned by `getStuff()`?

Comment: You might want to read up on [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Java).

Comment: You'll probably need to include more code and the error you're getting to get much help here. I tried what you've specified so far and it works fine. You must be leaving out something important.

Comment: You tell us nothing about your `add` method. How can we know, what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant to write classX.getStuff().add(B)

Comment: You still didn't answer Michael: what is the complaint?

Comment: Sorry the complaint was: add (capture <? extend A>) in Collection cannot be applied to B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following example as your X class.

For example,

```
public abstract <T extends A> Collection<T> getStuff();
```

You can also refer to [this threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901729/java-interface-generics-casting-problem).

Comment: Ahh thanks. That's exactly what I intended.   Just out of curiosity, what did the signature I used in my question do (abstract Collection<? extends A> getStuff())   compare to the answer that you gave?

Comment: In your case, the collection can’t put any value except null into a Collection<? extends A>. You can refer to the book (Effective Java By Joshua Bloch) here - http://goo.gl/cCrQo

Comment: Could you elaborate on why only null can go into a Collection<? extends A>  ?  I thought the signature would mean any type that extends A

Comment: You can take a look at the link I mentioned in the previous comment. I just copy the content of that book to you.